# Assistance in join to MYSQL table in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I need Assistance please

I have two tables (X) And (Y)

```
Table (X) have { ID , material_Name , Material_number )
Table (Y) have { ID , Material_Name , Total )
```

Both appear on data gridview.

So, From table (X) i select the material_name from combobox. then i write the number of material in the textbox. then i press add button to insert the value in the table(X).

So let we assume From table (X) i selected the material_name is ( Pen) and the Material_number was (10).Then after three days i inserted the same material name but the material_number was (20). 
So the total Pin= 30 for now.

So i want this result (30) appear to me on table (Y) in column (Total )on data Gridview. And it can increase or decrease according to the inserting Material_number from table (X)

As summary ,

In Table (X) :-

`First day >>> inserted 10 pens. & 5 soft`

`Second day >> inserted 20 pens .`

The total pens that i have it in right now 10+20= (30). And total soft that i have = (5).

In Table(Y):-

`The result (30)pens should be appear to me in column (Material_number)in the row of pens.`

`And the result of soft (5)should be appear to me in the column ( Material_number ) in the row of Soft` .

And like this for each material.

How can i do this?

Comment: You need to use an `insert trigger` to populate `Y` when a row is inserted in `X`.

Comment: I will be grateful if you can write the code for me

Comment: You mention c#, are you trying to write this into a program? or do you want to do it all on the database side?

Comment: From C# side and show the result on data gridview

Comment: Well, that part sounds like a different question.  What I've given you will update your mysql table `y` based on inserts into `x`.  Is that what you need?

Comment: my idea is when i add anything new in X the number of material increase in Y . and when i remove some of this material from X, the number of material will decrease in table Y .. i.e it's like counter to know how much i have from this material in my store.

Comment: Thats what my trigger will do.

Comment: the insert trigger will adding in to C# side or on db side ?

Comment: Triggers are a function of the database. (db side)  You would run that script in your mysql query editor

Comment: Were you able to find an answer here?  I'd be interested in your solution and if I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

An insert trigger will be run just before inserting into x.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_to_y BEFORE INSERT ON x
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE Y SET total = total + NEW.material_number 
    WHERE Material_Name = NEW.Material_Name ;
  END;
```

This way, when you run sql like this:

```
insert into x(material_name, material_number) values('soft', 5)
```

It will automatically update `y` to add the change.

Note that my example only handles updates.  If the value `soft` doesnt exist in the `Y` table, nothing will be updated.   But the trigger can be adjusted to handle that.